# How to set the default indicator for PrimeNG carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, carousel, primeng

I have implemented a carousel using PrimeNG in angular which looks like this:
[image: 1]

On page load the carousel is loaded with its last slide. I want the carousel to get loaded with the first slide by default. Also, notice the indicators at the bottom. The indicator is not highlighted on page load. It only gets highlighted when I click on indicators or the left arrow carousel navigation button. It does not work with the right button.

How do I solve these issues? Is this a bug or library issue?

PrimeNG Documentation - https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/carousel

My code:

```
        <p-carousel
          [value]="planDetails"
          styleClass="custom-carousel"
          [numVisible]="3"
          [numScroll]="1"
          [circular]="true"
          [autoplayInterval]="4000"
        >
          <ng-template let-plan pTemplate="item">
            <div class="centered-div">
              <div class="plans">
                <div class="card plan-card">
                  <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="plan-name">{{ plan?.planName }}</div>
                    <div class="plan-desc">
                      {{ plan?.description }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="plan-price">
                      <span class="plan-cost"
                        >$ {{ plan?.pricePerUser }}
                        <span>
                          <sup class="plan-currency">{{ plan?.currency }}</sup>
                        </span></span
                      >
                    </div>
                    <div class="billing-way">per user billed annually</div>

                    <div class="plan-upgrade-div centered-div">
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        class="remediator-blue-btn upgrade-btn centered-div"
                      >
                        <span class="button-text" (click)="onUpgrade(plan)">
                          Select
                        </span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <hr />

                    <div class="plan-features">Features</div>
                    <div
                      class="plan-feature-1"
                      *ngFor="let planfeature of plan.planFeatures"
                    >
                      <img
                        src="assets/images/orange-check.svg"
                        alt=""
                        class="feature-check"
                      />
                      <span class="feature-text">{{ planfeature }}</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
        </p-carousel>
```

SOLUTION: I change the numScroll to 3 and circular to false and my issue was solved

Comment: show your `.ts` file code as well?